# Polyglossia: multiple fonts with same language

Tags: polyglossia, syriac

I'm working with Syriac, which fortunately is supported by polyglossia. I might not have understood the documentation correctly, but I would like to use different fonts with the same language (cf. the three Syriac scripts [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_alphabet#Alphabet_forms)). For now, I have simply defined "estrangela" and "eastern" as separate languages to then set the respective font. This works generally, but throws warnings because of missing hyphenation patterns.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.  Have you tried changing fonts like you normally do in a one-language document?

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work.